# .append .prepend .html which should i use for this

Tags: jquery, html, append, prepend

```
   $('document').ready(function(){
$('#gfooter').append("<div style="text-align:center; width:800px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<img id="Image-Maps_3201211230108478" src="http://i.imgur.com/aHKja.png" usemap="#Image-Maps_3201211230108478" border="0" width="800" height="400" alt="" />
<map id="_Image-Maps_3201211230108478" name="Image-Maps_3201211230108478">
<area shape="rect" coords="84,184,253,353" href="www.facebook.com" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook"    />
<area shape="rect" coords="316,184,485,353" href="www.twitter.com" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter"    />
</map>
</div>
");
});
```

I'm trying to .append this bit of html into the div #gfooter. though it does not seem to work. Can anyone explain to my why?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you're putting something inside double quotes, the next time you use double quotes it "escapes". Therefore, use either one of these formats:

```
$.append("<a href='#'>link</a>");

$.append('<a href="#">link</a>');
```

I prefer the second one because it allows me to type my HTML like I usually do (using double quotes). Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok, so I escaped it. though it still is not working? any suggestions? I'll make a jsfiddle

Comment: actually I got it to work. I had to make all the html one line and fix the image map to show correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that as well, needs to be in one line :). Glad it works.

Comment: Could you also help me with something? I want to find http://i34.servimg.com/u/f34/17/74/08/92/icon_u11.png or #i_icon_online  and if it does not exist .html('<img src="" alt="" title="">');  I tried $(function() {
  $('.post:not("img#i_icon_online")').add('.post').html('<img src="http://i34.servimg.com/u/f34/17/74/08/92/icon_u11.png" id="i_icon_offline" alt="offline" title="offline">');
});​ did not work

Comment: You do not need to make it one line!  Just escape the new line.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/how-to-create-multiline-strings

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape quotes in string literals with a backslash.

```
var somestring = "<div id=\"something\">";
```

Comment: why not use this "<div id='something'>" instead ?

Comment: You certainly can. It is a matter of preference. Either way, you will have to escape one type of quote. Both JavaScript and HTML parsers except both types of quotes equally.

Comment: also '<div id="something\">' this way